# Why do I get a parse error for my binary tree definition?

Tags: haskell

When I type this code in Haskell:

```
data BT a = Empty | Fork a (BT a) (BT a) 
  Empty :: BT a
  Fork  :: a -> BT a -> BT a -> BT a
```

I get

> error: parse error on input `::'

I can't see what the issue is though, if I add `deriving (show)` to the top line, it changes to

> error: parse error on input `Empty'

Comment: What happens if you remove the last two lines? (In other words, why did you write them in the first place?)

Comment: The last two lines are already implicitly defined by Haskell since you gave the `data` definition. You must not include them.

Answer (score 6):

Either write it using the "legacy" uniform datatype syntax:

```
data BT a = Empty | Fork a (BT a) (BT a)
```

or use equivalent GADT syntax

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}

data BT a where 
  Empty :: BT a
  Fork  :: a -> BT a -> BT a -> BT a
```

But not both :)